# How to Manually create an Apache Windows Service

Tags: windows, apache, service

I accidentally removed my Apache windows service trying to install another Apache web server.  Does anyone know how I can create another Apache windows service from cmd? I tried "sc create ..." but I am missing a script on the end like -k start? Not sure what I need for the end of it...

I am running Apache 2.2

Thank you

Comment: to serverfault i'm think

Answer (score 93):

On Apache 2.4 the executable have changed name to httpd.exe, the command would be:

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache2.4"
```

With a name switch in order to give the service a distinct name.

Comment: I created a .bat file with the following text:

httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache2.4"
net start Apache2.4

Answer (score 11):

For older versions of Apache:

```
Apache.exe -k install
net start apache2
```

Answer (score 11):

Click `Win + R` and type `cmd`

Below Image shows how to install `Apache2.2` in windows

[image: How to install Apache2.2 in windows]

Default installation location of Apache2.2 is `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation` but in my pc I installed directly on `C:/` drive.

If you want to install Apache2.2 in Program Files folder then in type in command prompt as follows

`C:\>cd Program Files` ( Click Enter )

`C:\>Program Files>cd Apache Software Foundation` ( Click Enter )

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation>cd Apache2.2` ( Click Enter )

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2>cd bin` ( Click Enter )

in bin folder you will find `httpd.exe` file

`C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin>httpd.exe -k install`( Click Enter)

The successuful message is displayed in command prompt like above shown in the image.

Comment: Just to note: You can set an entire path with a single change-directory command for example: `cd c:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\bin`.

Comment: @MatthewBaker for better understanding who are newbies I wrote like this.

Answer (score 6):

On Apache 2.2, the command is:
httpd.exe -k install

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 or 8 right click the XAMPP Control Panel start (menu) shortcut and `Run As Administrator`. Then just click the service check boxes for Apache and/or MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Did not work for me using httpd.exe -k install, I had to register apache as a service using sc.exe using:

```
sc.exe create apache2.4 start= auto obj= "<account>" password= "<password>" DisplayName= "Apache 2.4" depend= "Tcpip/Afd" binpath= "\"c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.33\bin\httpd.exe\" -k runservice"
```

Comment: An alternative is to run "httpd.exe -k install" as an elevated process.

Answer (score 0):

After you past Apache file in your local machine,

1. Remember the location of the Apache file.
2. Open cmd in administrator mode.
3. Go to the location using cd command. `c:\Apache\bin` (Mine is 'Apache'. your file name may be different.)
4. type httpd.exe -k install
   After that you will receive a line like '...service is successfully installed.'

Now, your machine has Apache service.