# I can't get Apache to work for some reason

Tags: apache, windows-7

For some reason Apache just doesn't seem to want to work.  I have been trying so many things to try and fix it but with no luck.  At first there was programs blocking port 80.  A few of the programs I tried to stop on port 80 are skype, World Wide Web Publishing Service, IIS(Internet Information Services), and NT Kernal & System.  Then I ran Apache in the cmd.  I typed: cd:/apache/bin then I typed httpd.exe but nothing happened and the cursor just kept blinking on the next line.  I also went to ApacheMonitor in the bin file and ran that, then went to the little icon on the bottom and clicked start but it just said  The requested operation has failed!  I don't know what to do now.

I have windows 7.

Comment: I think that this question should go to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to Install [Apache as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613720/how-to-manually-create-an-apache-windows-service).

However, if you want to start Apache via command prompt. First thing you check if the syntax in your conf files is ok. Open a command prompt as an Administrator. Change to Apache bin directory and use below command.

`httpd -t`

If it returns `Syntax OK`, that's a good news. Errors will be displayed if any. Fix all errors.

Once syntax looks ok, run below command to start Apache.

`httpd -k start`

It should start your Apache. If it doesn't check `/logs/error.log` and see what's going on.

Good Luck!

Comment: I tried that and this popped up in the error log(nothing happened in the cmd):
Starting the Apache2.4 service
[Tue Dec 23 14:56:14.534412 2014] [mpm_winnt:crit] [pid 9136:tid 280] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00378: Apache2.4: Failed to start the service process.

Comment: Did you get any response from `httpd -t` ? Do you have write access on Apache ?

Comment: I didn't get a response.  I should have write access on Apache because i'm the admin on this computer.

Comment: Also, check if you have `httpd.conf` in `/Apache/conf`. I will take a look and update the answer as necessary.